# Computing Poisson Random Variable

Tags: probability

I am working on this question:

> A text file contains 6000 characters. When the file is sent by
>   e-mail from one machine to another, each character (independently of
>   all other characters) has probability 0.001 of being corrupted. Use a
>   Poisson random variable to estimate the probability that the file is
>   transferred without error.

*My solution so far:*

- $N = 6000$ since there are 6000 trials
- the probability of success of each trial (of not being corrupted) is $1-0.001=0.999$
- Let X be the random variable that represents the number of sucesses

So I use the Poission distribution formula:
$$P\{X = k\} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}$$

So I want to find the probability of 6000 successes, which means that the file transferred successfully without any errors:
$$\lambda = N\cdot p = 6000(0.999)=5994$$
$$P\{X = 6000\} = \frac{e^{-5994}(5994)^{6000}}{6000!}$$

However this number cant be calculated by my calculator so I assuming that I have did something wrong. But all my working out makes sense so far so I don't know where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It's a lot easier to calculate the probability of 0 failures instead of 6,000 successes.

Comment: Is the probability of 0 errors equivalent to the probability of 6000 successes of no errors?

Comment: @katambit, yes it is.